# A problem in probability on 3-dim unit ball

Tags: probability

Find the density of the $xy$ coordinates conditional on $Z = 0$.

First, I don't really understand what the question mean $xy$ coordinates, is it asking to figure out $P(XY=a|Z=0)$?

If it is, then, how to calculate the area of xy surface? (It seems a calculus problem... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a distribution $f(x,y,z)$ defined on the unit ball $\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1\}$, you want to find $f(x,y|z)$ for $z=0$.

Note that $f(x,y|z) = \frac{f(x,y,z)}{f(z)} = \frac{f(x,y,z)}{\iint f(x,y,z) dx dy}$. Then, take $z=0$ to get the density of the $x,y$ coordinates conditioned on $Z=0$.

Comment: Ya, of course, $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} \pi r^{3}}$, and it is easily to find $f(z)$ (and I found it). But I'm not sure the question is asking $f(x,y|z)$ or $f(xy|z)$

Comment: Also, I wander how to calculate $f(xy|z)$

Comment: Well, in the latter case you wouldn't say "coordinates". So its $f(x,y|z)$. If you're still unsure, ask the person who gave you the problem set.

Comment: As for calculating the distribution of $XY|Z$, you should have $f(x,y|z)$ and you can write out the integral for $P(XY \leq a | Z=z)= \int_{xy\leq a} f(x,y|z) dx dy$ and differentiate it to get the result.